# Sphinx sql_query_killlist on a distributed remote index

Tags: sphinx

The [sphinx documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-killlist%20%22sphinx%20documentation) says that `sql_query_killlist` can be used with a distributed remote index:

> Note that in the distributed index setup, K-lists are local to every node in the cluster. They are not get transmitted over the network when sending queries. (Because that might be too much of an impact when the K-list is huge.) You will need to setup a separate per-server K-lists in that case.

I can get `sql_query_killlist` working with a distributed "local" index that looks like this:

```
index mydistributedindex
{
  type = distributed
  local = main_index
  local = delta_index
}
```

The `sql_query_killlist` sits on the source of the `delta_index` and it works.

I tried to change `mydistributedindex` above setting these all as "remote agents" pointing to localhost. The querys still work, but the `sql_query_killlist` no longer works:

```
index mydistributedindex
{
  type = distributed
  agent = localhost:9312:main_index
  agent = localhost:9312:delta_index
}
```

If i want `mydistributedindex` to span accross multiple remote agents, I cannot find an example where `sql_query_killlist` will work in line with the documentation quoted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=14337) by [barryhunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65548/barryhunter) this will work:

```
index mydistributedindex
{
  type = distributed
  agent = localhost:9312:server1index
}

index server1index
{
  type = distributed
  local = main_index
  local = delta_index
}
```